# Read Xml Field From Image field Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, image, type-conversion, blob

I am trying to change the code below and read it from the image field

```sql
        DECLARE @xml XML
        SELECT @xml= x FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @XMLFILE + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
```

How Can I Convert To Xml Type?

```
SELECT @xml= FileField FROM FileListTable (FileField is İmage Field)
```

Comment: What do you mean by an "image" field? As in a jpeg or png? That can't be converted to `xml`; their content is nothing like XML. If you mean the `image` data type: 1. Why are you using `image`, when it's been deprecated since 2005. 2. What's wrong with `CONVERT`? (Though you would likely need to nest them.)

Comment: image is not a picture format, image is blob data type in sql server so i upload xml file to image(blob) field and i need to convert(cast) xml field type for insert record from it

Comment: I *assume*, therefore, by the prior comment you mean the `image` data type, so again, *why* are you using `image`? it's been deprecated since 2005; that's 17 years ago. Why are you not using `MAX` length data types?

Comment: i'm working sql server 2008 and 2014 and it isnt deprecated yet, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=IMPORTANT!,and%20varbinary(max)%20instead.

Comment: ... Did you not read that link you just posted..? *"**IMPORTANT! ntext, text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead."* /sigh

Comment: yes i read it but future version and Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)

Comment: Also see this old [article](https://documentation.help/sql.2005.setupsql9/c10eeaa5-3d3c-49b4-a4bd-5dc4fb190142.htm) confirming deprecation in 2005. It's also documented in the deprecated features; the older supported version is SQL Server 2016 which confirms it is still deprecated. [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It's deprecated, 3angle. Stop using it. Converting a `MAX` based data type to `xml` is trivial: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT @xml = CAST(CAST(FileField AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML)
FROM FileListTable
```

Whether this works or not, may depend on how the XML was converted to the IMAGE data type before being inserted into your table.  [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=881de8e160946c5204c0bc0702f0b343) exercises various ways of inserting XML into an IMAGE column and several ways (both good and bad) to try to get it out. Almost surprisingly, the cast to VARBINARY(MAX) and then to XML seems to handle the cases demonstrated.